# Rotate rectangles - ANGLE returned - Opencv

Tags: opencv, rotation, orientation, rectangles

I have a problem understanding how OpenCV works when it comes to RotatedRect.

I have extracted a contour and I then try to fit a rotated rectangle over it. The angles that I keep getting range only in 0 to -90. Even if I have the contour directing the other way by flipping it, I still get 0 to -90 angles.

My problem is to make sure the contour lies at 0' degrees. And for that I have to calculated the orientation and then rotate accordingly.

How are these angles represented in OpenCV (2.4.3)?

Regards
Wajih

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956124/minarearect-angles-unsure-about-the-angle-returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases `RotatedRect` angle can be the same for contour rotated 180 deg. The best way to figure out if it happens in your case is to draw fitted RotatedRect.

I think that more suited for your case are contour moments.

See my answers there:
[Rotation and scale invariant template matching in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601583/rotation-and-scale-invariant-template-matching-in-opencv/12608877#12608877)
and there:
[Find the orientation of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330269/find-the-orientation-of-an-image?answertab=active#tab-top)

You can compute moments with `cv::Moments` : http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=moments#cv.Moments

Comment: Thanks, let me go through them and see what I need extra to do.

Answer (score 1):

i found out that the angle is between the counter and Y axis (from LearningOpenCV) .are you expecting it to be from X axis?