# How would I tell the orientation and direction of a moving object using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, orientation, image-recognition

I am trying to track a moving insect and the tracking is not the hard part. I am using cv2.minAreaRect and I have tried using the angle of the rectangle as an indicator for the orientation but apparently it does not return the angle in a range of 0-360. See here for more explanation: [Not sure about angle returned from minAreaRect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956124/minarearect-angles-unsure-about-the-angle-returned).

I've also tried using cv2.contourArea because it can provide information about the orientation of the contours but I don't think it's going to be much of help in deciding which part of the contour is the "head".

I'm not really asking for a solid solution(if you know one, please feel free to share), it's more of a brainstorming conversation on how one would go about determining the orientation of a moving object using information from its contours, minAreaRect angle, etc.

Please feel free to chime in with your suggestions and I will try them out. Thanks you so much in advance!

Comment: Consider the center of the rect at time t and t+1. Doesn't the vector between these two points give you orientation and direction?

Comment: add images (input, detected contours, computed rects etc) and result values (orientation angles) please...

Comment: Further to @Micka: [ask]

Comment: Hi did you solve the problem with the direction? If yes please share it here, Thanks!